# EF Core Add-Migration fails with System.TypeLoadException

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use EF core 2.0 to build a SQLite database, (a simple one). When i try to do Add-Migration on the following code it fails with the code below.

```
public class RothSensor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public double CurrentTemp { get; set; }

    public double TargetTemp { get; set; }

    public enum _mode
    {
        Normal = 0,
        Night = 1,
        Holliday = 2
    }

    public _mode Mode { get; set; }

    public double MinimumTemp { get; set; }

    public double MaximumTemp { get; set; }

    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public RothUnit Unit { get; set; }

}

public class RothUnit
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<RothSensor> Sensors { get; set; }


}

public class HADataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RothUnit> RUnits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RothSensor> RSensors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source = HomeAutomation.db");
    }
}
```

the error code is:-

> PM> Add-Migration HomeAutomationDB
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>      at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2.Node.SetOrAdd(TKey key, TValue value, IComparer`1 keyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, Boolean overwriteExistingValue, Boolean& replacedExistingValue, Boolean& mutated)
>      at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2.Node.SetItem(TKey key, TValue value, IComparer`1 keyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, Boolean& replacedExistingValue, Boolean& mutated)
>      at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2.Builder.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.GetNavigationCandidates(EntityType entityType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.FindRelationshipCandidates(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverRelationships(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__0(Object k)
>      at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Could not load type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   PM>

I have tried every possible tips i could find online but it still fails. The only way it could pass is if i remove the List from the RothUnit model and remove the last line in RothSensor class.

I don't know if it is something with EF core or my code. Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you defined the relationship between Rothsensor and Rothunit ???

Comment: Yes I even tried to explicitly define the relationship instead of the letting EF discover it, which is where it fails. But I don't know why it fails!

Comment: Have you defined any primary key or foreign key for the entities within modelbuilder ??

Comment: I used the following code and it still fails:- protected override void On model creating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {  modelBuilder.Entity<RothSensor>().HasOne(u => u.U it).WithMany(s =>s.Sensors).HasForeignKey(u =>u.UnitId);} Is it what you mean?!

Comment: after some googling i think there may be something wrong with packages installed.. have you got " microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite.design " package ?

Comment: Interesting! I think I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design will try Sql.Design when I am at home. Will update you later.

Comment: it should be SQLite.Design

Comment: I'm having same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging and submitting an issue to the EntityFrameworkCore GitHub page. It appears that this is an issue with the EF Core 2.0 itself. They are aware of that and it has been addressed in future releases.

There is a somehow workaround that you can find it in the following link:-
[GitHub EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9666)

The workaround is the courtesy of the EF core team.